# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test)

Tags: java, maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to run some tests and generate a JaCoCo coverage report on a project and keep getting this error.

Here is my error log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project empire-db: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
```

My plugins under the build section of the pom file are as follows:

```
<plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.2.1</version>            
</plugin>
           
<plugin>
                 <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                 <executions>
                   <execution>
                     <id>prepare-agent</id>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                     </goals>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                     <id>report</id>
                     <phase>test</phase>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>report</goal>
                     </goals>
                    
                   </execution>
                 </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am using Java 15.0.2 and Maven 3.8.5
The project cleans and compiles just fine, I only encounter this issue when testing. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Fix the tests first: ` There are test failures.`... why using such an old version of maven-surefire-plugin... 3.0.0-M7 https://maven.apache.org/plugins

Comment: Thank you, using a more recent version did the trick !